# xargs/curl is not processing all urls: getting ERROR curl: (6) Could not resolve host: h

Tags: curl, xargs

I'm using `xargs` + `curl` to process a file containing quite a large (more than 1000) number of urls.

That file `files.txt` looks somewhat like this

```
...
https://some.image.jpg?{foo}.{bar}
...
```

and I'm running

```
xargs -n 1 curl -o "#1.#2" < files.txt
```

which is correctly downloading `some.image.jpg` into a file `foo.bar`, but only for the first 40 or so urls, sometimes some more, sometimes less. Then it terminates with error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: h
```

If I remove all urls from the list preceding the url that breaks, and run again, this time the url (now it's the first one) works, but now it breaks again at no. 80 (40 resp.) with the same error.

So the urls are fine, manual download is no problem.

I should mention that I'm using GOW (https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with `xargs`, because it's working smoothly using a for loop instead:

```
FOR /F %i IN (files.txt) DO curl -o "#1.#2" %i
```